# wave.Error: unknown format: 3 arises when trying to convert a wav file into text in Python

Tags: python, wav, speech-to-text, voice-recording

I need to record an audio from the microphone and convert it into text. I have tried this conversion process using several audio clips that I downloaded from the web and it works fine. But when I try to convert the audio clip I recorded from the microphone it gives the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition__init__.py", line 203, in **enter**
    self.audio_reader = wave.open(self.filename_or_fileobject, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 510, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 164, in **init**
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 144, in initfp
    self._read_fmt_chunk(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wave.py", line 269, in _read_fmt_chunk
    raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
wave.Error: unknown format: 3

The code I am trying is as follows.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

# recording from the microphone
fs = 44100  # Sample rate
seconds = 3  # Duration of recording

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file
sound = "output.wav"
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(sound) as source:
     recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
     print("Converting audio file to text...")
     audio = recognizer.listen(source)

     try:
          text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
          print("The converted text:" + text)

     except Exception as e:
          print(e)
```

I looked at the similar questions that were answered, and they say that we need to convert it into a different wav format. Can someone provide me a code or a library that I can use for this conversion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share the link on the audio file

Comment: This is the link for the audio file.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGsQbH2dqbiZ--4fI4atAhQC6S9YcUrd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wrote the file in float format:

```
soxi output.wav 

Input File     : 'output.wav'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 25-bit
Duration       : 00:00:03.00 = 132300 samples = 225 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 1.06M
Bit Rate       : 2.82M
Sample Encoding: 32-bit Floating Point PCM
```

and wave module can't read it.

To store int16 format do like this:

```
import numpy as np
myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording.astype(np.int16))  # Save as WAV file in 16-bit format
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer solved the wave error. But now I cannot hear anything in the output.wav file. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 6):

#### Method 1

You can't hear anything because you cast floating point value to an integer which is incorrect. The floating point values in a signal go from -1 to 1 in a WAV file and the 16 bit PCM (integer) values go from -32,768 to 32,767. So essentially, your signal got converted from something like 
`[-1.4240753e-05,  4.3602209e-05,  1.0526689e-06, ...,
        1.7763522e-02,  1.6644333e-02,  6.7148944e-03]` 

 to 
`[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]`

The above conversion is incorrect.

To correctly convert the file into integers (PCM format), you would need to **convert** and not **cast**. One way of doing this is given below `def float2pcm(sig, dtype='int16'):
    sig = np.asarray(sig)
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)

```
i = np.iinfo(dtype)
abs_max = 2 ** (i.bits - 1)
offset = i.min + abs_max
return (sig * abs_max + offset).clip(i.min, i.max).astype(dtype)`
```

so you can use the following code just after you use the `sd.wait` line

```
float2pcm(myrecording)
```

#### Method 2

Another (more simpler) way of solving your problem would be to use the `sounddevice` library's capability to do this internally by calling the following function for recording instead.

```
import numpy as np
myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype=np.int16)
```

Comment: Both methods together worked for me. Make sure you have enabled your Input Microphone Volume trackbar. On Ubuntu I had to enable Settings -> Sound -> Input -> click Volume button on far right and drag the slider to highest point, far right. Then it will record your microphone for the duration specified in code above.