# Deepspeech does not recognize input audio file recorded from PC microphone

Tags: python, audio, mozilla-deepspeech

trying to convert audio to text using DeepSpeech, it works fine with the default audio files from Mozilla/DeepSpeech. but when i try to record audio from my PC's microphone and feed it to the model, it raises an error( 'wave.Error: unknown format: 3'). I am using sounddevice library to record audio. I tried to change sample rate and channels number but didn't work. I know that the error is caused by the 'wave' function, but i couldn't figure it out. Please Help

My code:

```
from deepspeech import Model
import numpy as np
import os
import wave
from playsound import playsound
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
model_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.8.2-models.pbmm'
lm_file_path = 'deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer'

beam_width = 500
lm_alpha = 0.93
lm_beta = 1.18

model = Model(model_file_path)
model.enableExternalScorer(lm_file_path)

model.setScorerAlphaBeta(lm_alpha, lm_beta)
model.setBeamWidth(beam_width)


def read_wav_file(filename):
    with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as w:
        rate = w.getframerate()
        frames = w.getnframes()
        buffer = w.readframes(frames)
        print("Rate:", rate)
        print("Frames:", frames)
        print("Buffer Len:", len(buffer))

    return buffer, rate


def transcribe_batch(audio_file):
    buffer, rate = read_wav_file(audio_file)
    data16 = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.int16)
    return model.stt(data16)


fs = 48000  # Sample rate
seconds = 5  # Duration of recording
myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs,     channels=1)
sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file
playsound('output.wav')


trans = transcribe_batch('output.wav')
print("trancribed message: ", trans)

with open('subtitle.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(trans)


print("executed successfully")
```

Error:

```
TensorFlow: v2.3.0-6-g23ad988fcd
DeepSpeech: v0.9.3-0-gf2e9c858
2021-11-14 00:57:24.539394: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This     TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the     following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/deepspeech-wenv/test.py", line 48, in <module>
    trans = transcribe_batch('output.wav')
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/deepspeech-wenv/test.py", line 35, in transcribe_batch
    buffer, rate = read_wav_file(audio_file)
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/deepspeech-wenv/test.py", line 23, in read_wav_file
    with wave.open(filename, 'rb') as w:
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 499, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 163, in     __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 143, in initfp
    self._read_fmt_chunk(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\wave.py", line 260, in _read_fmt_chunk
    raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
wave.Error: unknown format: 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wave.Error: unknown format: 3 arises when trying to convert a wav file into text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352850/wave-error-unknown-format-3-arises-when-trying-to-convert-a-wav-file-into-text)

Comment: I tried this method and the code executed successfully, but deepspeech didn't convert my speech to text. the output from deepspeech is blank! How can i solve that?

Comment: I’d interpret those as 2 separate problems. Delete this question and ask why the output is blank. Don’t forget to verify that the wav (in the correct format) contains audio data (I.e play the reformatted wav and make sure you hear something)